# Error Creating default object from empty value in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

so I get this error each time I try to edit something.
My best guess that I didn't link something properly.
or it just doesn't work at all.

This is the URL I have when I get the error:
http://sde2.test/ticket/%7Bid%7D
As far as I know, it just doesn't get the right id when I try to save it.

Anyway thanks in advance for the answers!

This is my ticket controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Ticket;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Redirect, Response;

class TicketController extends Controller
{
    public function setUpdate($ticketId, Request $request)
    {
        $ticket = Ticket::find($ticketId);

        $ticket->name = $request->name;
        $ticket->email = $request->email;
        $ticket->phonenr = $request->phonenr;
        $ticket->desc = $request->desc;
        $ticket->update = $request->update;


        $ticket ->save();

        return Redirect::to('ticket')->withSuccess('Het is gelukt, ticket is geupdate!');
    }
```

And my ticket model:

```
class Ticket extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'phonenr',
        'desc',
        'update'
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at'
    ];
}
```

and this is my ticket blade:

```
<body>
<br>
<h1 class="d-flex justify-content-center">Tickets</h1>
<br>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @if($message = Session::get('success'))
            <div class="row alert alert-success">
                <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
            </div>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container-lg d-flex justify-content-start">
    <form action="/ticketzoek" method="get">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="zoeken" placeholder="Zoeken op naam.." class="form-control">
            <span class="input-group-prepend">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Zoeken</button>
                </span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
<div class="container-lg d-flex justify-content-center table-responsive-md">
    <table id="tickets" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Naam</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Telefoon nummer</th>
            <th>Probleem</th>
            <th>Updates</th>
            <th>Datum ingediend</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Aanpassen</th>
            <th>Verhelpen</th>
            <th>Verwijderen</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        @foreach($tickets as $ticket)
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $ticket->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $ticket->email }}</td>
                <td>{{ $ticket->phonenr }}</td>
                <td>{{ $ticket->desc }}</td>
                <td>{{ $ticket->update }}</td>
                <td>{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($ticket->created_at)->format('d-m-Y') }}</td>
                @if($ticket->solved == 0)
                    <td><a class="text-danger">Niet opgelost</a></td>
                @endif
                <td>
                    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view_{{$ticket->id}}">Aanpassen</button>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="view_{{$ticket->id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="loaning" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="loaning">Tickets gegevens</h5>
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="row m-0" style="background-color: #005b82; padding-top: 20px">
                                        <h2 class="d-flex justify-content-center">Aanpassen ticket</h2>
                                        <form action="ticket/{id}" method="post">
                                            @csrf
                                            <br>
                                            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="name">Naam:</label>
                                                    <input type="name"  class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ $ticket->name }}">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="email">Email:</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $ticket->email}}">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="phonenr">Telefoon nummer:</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phonenr" value="{{ $ticket->phonenr}}">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="desc">Probleem:</label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="desc" value="{{ $ticket->desc}}">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                                                <div class="col-md-6">
                                                    <label for="update">Updates:</label>
                                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="update">{{ $ticket->update}}</textarea>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <br>
                                            <br>
                                            <div class="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Sluiten</button>
                                                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Aanpassen</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('ticket.approve', ['id' => $ticket->id]) }}">
                        @csrf
                        <input type="hidden" name="ticketID" value="{{$ticket->id}}"/>
                        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
                            Klaar
                        </button>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <form method="post" action="{{ route('ticket.delete', ['id' => $ticket->id]) }}">
                        @csrf
                        @method('DELETE')
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Verwijderen</button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        @endforeach
    </table>
</div>
</body>
```

here is my web.php

```
    Route::get('/ticket',  'TicketController@show');
    Route::post('/ticket/{id}', 'TicketController@setUpdate')->name('ticket.update');
    Route::post('/ticket/{id}', 'TicketController@setSolved')->name('ticket.approve');
    Route::delete('/ticket/{id}', 'TicketController@setDelete')->name('ticket.delete');
```

Comment: You cant use same URI, with same method `Route::post('/ticket/{id}'……`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you can't edit the model because of wrong url.
The solution is to change some code in the blade:

`<form action="ticket/{id}" method="post">`

to

`<form method="post" action="{{ route('ticket.update', ['id' => $ticket->id]) }}">`
Also check the `approve` and `update` methods, they have the same url and HTTP method, don't think it's good.

Comment: If I do it I get an error route not defined:
Route [ticket.update] not defined. (View: C:\laragon\www\SDE2\resources\views\admin\ticketpage.blade.php)

Comment: run `php artisan route:list` in the console and update post with list of existing routes

Comment: strange it won't update the list when I try php artisan route:cache or
php artisan route:clear

Comment: okay i just changed the name in web.php and the form action that worked..